# Use onclick on a button to start javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, function, onclick

Hi there I'm pretty new to using functions and onclick actions to call javascript so I could do with some help. Basically, I've installed a plugin on WordPress which adds a button to the page in the form of a widget and once clicked it starts a script. However, I don't like their button so I'm trying to code my own but I want it to start the script like there's.

Here's the script code:

```
/*
* Timely BookButton plugin
* Example usage:
* var button = new timelyButton('doedayspa');
*
* Booking process can be kicked off manually by calling the start method  on     the button instance e.g.
* button.start();
*
*/

// Need this for legacy support of older versions of the BookingButton
var timelyButton;

(function () {

"use strict";
var context = window;

var mobile = {
    Android: function () {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ? true : false;
    },
    BlackBerry: function () {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) ? true : false;
    },
    iOS: function () {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPod/i) ? true : false;
    },
    Windows: function () {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i) ? true : false;
    },
    any: function () {
        return (mobile.Android() || mobile.BlackBerry() || mobile.iOS() || mobile.Windows());
    }
};


timelyButton = function (id, opts) {

    var options = opts || {};
    var businessId = id;
    var resellerCode = options.reseller || resellerCode || '';
    var productId = options.product || productId || '';
    var categoryId = options.category || categoryId || '';
    var staffId = options.staff || staffId || '';
    var locationId = options.location || locationId || '';
    var giftVoucherId = options.giftVoucherId || giftVoucherId || '';
    var isPurchaseButton = options.isPurchaseButton != null ? options.isPurchaseButton : false; // default not a purchase
    var dontCreateButton = !!options.dontCreateButton;
    window.timelyBookFrame = {};
    var XD;
    var style = options.style || 'light';
    var buttonId = options.buttonId || false;
    var bookButton;

    var scriptSource = (function() {
        var script = document.getElementById('timelyScript');
        if (script.getAttribute.length !== undefined) {
            return script.src;
        }
        return script.getAttribute('src', -1);
    }());

    var isOwnImage = !!options.imgSrc;
    var imgButtonType = isPurchaseButton ? "purchase-buttons" : "book-buttons";
    var imgSrc = options.imgSrc || getDomain() + '/images/' + imgButtonType + '/button_' + style + '@2x.png';
    var hoverSrc = getDomain() + '/images/' + imgButtonType + '/button_' + style + '_hover@2x.png';
    var activeSrc = getDomain() + '/images/' + imgButtonType + '/button_' + style + '_active@2x.png';
    var locationUrl = (isPurchaseButton ? '/giftvoucher/details/' : '/booking/location/') + businessId;

    function init() {
        if (dontCreateButton) return true;
        if (isOwnImage) {
            bookButton = document.createElement('a');
            bookButton.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
            bookButton.onclick = eventHandler.prototype.Book;
            bookButton.innerHTML = '<img src=\'' + imgSrc + '\' border=\'0\' />';
        } else {
            bookButton = document.createElement('a');
            bookButton.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imgSrc + ")";
            bookButton.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
            bookButton.style.backgroundPosition = "0px 0px";
            bookButton.style.backgroundSize = (isPurchaseButton ? "220px" : "162px") + " 40px";
            bookButton.style.width = isPurchaseButton ? "220px" : "162px";
            bookButton.style.height = "40px";
            bookButton.style.display = "inline-block";
            bookButton.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
            bookButton.onclick = eventHandler.prototype.Book;
            bookButton.innerHTML += '<img src="' + hoverSrc + '" style="display:none;" border=\'0\' />';
            bookButton.innerHTML += '<img src="' + activeSrc + '" style="display:none;" border=\'0\' />';
            bookButton.onmouseenter = function() { this.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + hoverSrc + ")"; };
            bookButton.onmouseout = function () { this.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imgSrc + ")"; };
            bookButton.onmousedown = function () { this.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + activeSrc + ")"; };
            bookButton.onmouseup = function () { this.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + hoverSrc + ")"; };
        }
        var insertionPoint = findInsertionPoint(buttonId);
        insertAfter(bookButton, insertionPoint);
    }

    function findInsertionPoint(buttonId) {
        var insertionPoint = false;
        if (buttonId) {
            insertionPoint = document.getElementById(buttonId);
        } else {
            if (("currentScript" in document)) {
                insertionPoint = document.currentScript;
            } else {
                var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
                insertionPoint = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
            }
        }
        return insertionPoint;
    }

    function getDomain() {
        return ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + scriptSource.match( /:\/\/(.[^/]+)/ )[1];
    }

    function startBooking() {
        var url = "";
        if (resellerCode) {
            url += '&reseller=' + resellerCode;
        }
        if (productId) {
            url += '&productId=' + productId;
        }
        if (categoryId) {
            url += '&categoryId=' + categoryId;
        }
        if (staffId) {
            url += '&staffId=' + staffId;
        }
        if (locationId) {
            url += '&locationId=' + locationId;
        }
        if (giftVoucherId) {
            url += '&giftVoucherId=' + giftVoucherId;
        }

        if (window.innerWidth < 768 || mobile.any()) {
            url = getDomain() + locationUrl + "?mobile=true" + url;
            window.location.href = url;
            return;
        }
        window.timelyBookFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
        window.timelyBookFrame.className = 'timely-book-frame';
        window.timelyBookFrame.style.cssText = 'width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 99999999;';
        window.timelyBookFrame.setAttribute('frameBorder', 0);
        window.timelyBookFrame.setAttribute('allowTransparency', 'true');
        url = getDomain() + (isPurchaseButton ? '/giftvoucher' : '/booking') + '/overlay/' + businessId + '?x' + url;
        url += '#' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.href);
        window.timelyBookFrame.src = url;
        window.timelyBookFrame.style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(window.timelyBookFrame);
        var element = document.getElementById('timely-lightbox');
        if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null) {
            $('#timely-lightbox').fadeOut();
        }
    }

    function insertAfter(f, n) {
        var p = n.parentNode;
        if (n.nextSibling) {
            p.insertBefore(f, n.nextSibling);
        } else {
            p.appendChild(f);
        }
    }

    function eventHandler() {
        // prototype instance
    }

    eventHandler.prototype.Book = function() {
        startBooking();
    };

    // everything is wrapped in the XD function to reduce namespace collisions
    XD = function () {

        var interval_id,
            last_hash,
            cache_bust = 1,
            attached_callback,
            window = context;

        return {
            postMessage: function (message, target_url, target) {
                if (!target_url) {
                    return;
                }
                target = target || parent; // default to parent
                if (window['postMessage']) {
                    // the browser supports window.postMessage, so call it with a targetOrigin
                    // set appropriately, based on the target_url parameter.
                    target['postMessage'](message, target_url.replace(/([^:]+:\/\/[^\/]+).*/, '$1'));
                } else if (target_url) {
                    // the browser does not support window.postMessage, so use the window.location.hash fragment hack
                    target.location = target_url.replace(/#.*$/, '') + '#' + (+new Date) + (cache_bust++) + '&' + message;
                }
            },
            receiveMessage: function (callback, source_origin) {
                // browser supports window.postMessage
                if (window['postMessage']) {
                    // bind the callback to the actual event associated with window.postMessage
                    if (callback) {
                        attached_callback = function (e) {
                            if ((typeof source_origin === 'string' && e.origin !== source_origin)
                                || (Object.prototype.toString.call(source_origin) === "[object Function]" && source_origin(e.origin) === !1)) {
                                return !1;
                            }
                            callback(e);
                        };
                    }
                    if (window['addEventListener']) {
                        window[callback ? 'addEventListener' : 'removeEventListener']('message', attached_callback, !1);
                    } else {
                        window[callback ? 'attachEvent' : 'detachEvent']('onmessage', attached_callback);
                    }
                } else {
                    // a polling loop is started & callback is called whenever the location.hash changes
                    interval_id && clearInterval(interval_id);
                    interval_id = null;
                    if (callback) {
                        interval_id = setInterval(function () {
                            var hash = document.location.hash,
                                re = /^#?\d+&/;
                            if (hash !== last_hash && re.test(hash)) {
                                last_hash = hash;
                                callback({ data: hash.replace(re, '') });
                            }
                        }, 100);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }();

    // setup a callback to handle the dispatched MessageEvent. if window.postMessage is supported the passed
    // event will have .data, .origin and .source properties. otherwise, it will only have the .data property.
    XD.receiveMessage(function (message) {

        if (message.data == 'close') {
            var element = document.getElementById('timely-lightbox');
            if (typeof (element) != 'undefined' && element != null) {
                $('#timely-lightbox').show();
            }
            if (window.timelyBookFrame && window.timelyBookFrame.parentNode) window.timelyBookFrame.parentNode.removeChild(window.timelyBookFrame);
        }
        if (message.data == 'open' && window.timelyBookFrame) {
            window.timelyBookFrame.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }, getDomain());

    init();

    // expose the BookButton API
    return {
        start: function() {
            startBooking();
        }
    };
};

})();
```

So how can I run this javascript when I click the button?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide button html code

Comment: If you don't like their button it sounds like you don't like its appearance. Changing somethings appearance is a job for CSS. You should be to find your  plugin's CSS easy enough then edit the bits pertaining to the button. No need to reinvent  the wheel (or the button)

Comment: I’ve not been totally clear here, I’ve already made the button as the site uses Visual Composer to create the layout and buttons etc. There is an onclick input to add your own action and in that box I’ve added ‘button.start();’ like it says in the script above however nothing happens when the button is clicked? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a script tag automatically if the button has been clicked.

```js
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
 const script = document.createElement("script");
 script.src = 'my-other-file.js';
 document.head.appendChild(script);
})
```

```html
<button id="myButton">Load JS File</button>
```

Comment: I’ve not been totally clear here, I’ve already made the button as the site uses Visual Composer to create the layout and buttons etc. There is an onclick input to add your own action and in that box I’ve added ‘button.start();’ like it says in the script above however nothing happens when the button is clicked? Am I missing something?

Comment: @AlexRussell no, this will definitely not work, since  `start` is not a function. It is an returned object of an anonym function with the variable `timelyButton`. In this case run the function `timelyButton()`. Make sure to pass the parameters `id` and `opts`, if needed.

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it still doesn't action anything. This is how the button is coded: `<a href class="custom-link btn btn-lg border-width-0 btn-default btn-icon-left" onclick="timelyButton()">Book Now</a>`

Comment: Here is a screenshot to the Visual Composer element: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2wq0p117hozkdlx/Screen%20Shot%202018-07-05%20at%2010.56.03.png?dl=1

Comment: @AlexRussell it depends on whether the JS file is loaded or not (just check your source code). If it is, it depends on WHERE it is loaded. Best case it would be placed BEFORE that JS file with your onClick event listener.

Comment: The JS file is loaded and it's loaded in the head of the page. I'm trying to mimic the action of the first book now button on this page https://thorpeandbrown.briomedia.co.uk/book/ but I don't want the button to look like that. I want it to look like the button below it. People have suggested CSS and yes I've styled my own button but I just can't get it to activate the script when clicked.

Comment: @AlexRussell ok, your problem is that your button is a `<a>` tag. So if you click on it, of course you'll get directed to another or to the same page and a reload is not what you want. So instead of using the `onClick` of your plugin, just use your own JS file, then you could use `event.preventDefault()`, so it will not forward you. The easiest way would be styling that button that already works with your own CSS.